# Token for field in field collection

Tags: tokens, entities

I have a [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) with 3 fields (title, image and link). I'd like to link the title and image to the value of the link field.

I'm using the [linked field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field) to make the fields linkable and enabled the [token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token). Yet the fields from my field collection aren't in my available tokens list. They also can't be found in admin/help/token

How do I link a field from a field collection to the value of another field from that same collection? Or how do I find the correct token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in enabling the entity_token module. This expanded my available tokens list to include the fields within the field collection.